# Can HTML5 access private data like SMSes or contacts on iPhone/iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, html

I'm not familiar with phone OSes. Can html5 do this on iPhone ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple answer: NO

SMSs access isn't even possible for native apps. Contact access can be done via "low level" C-APIs.

Comment: Peh. Thats why I don't like Apple.

Answer (score 0):

No cant access the SMS, you can't even access SMS from the SDK or mail for that matter.

Not sure about contact, you hace acces to the contact via the API, but not sure if HTML5 has any contacts methods.